# Как правильно получить `listFiles()` из dir после подтверждения пермишена?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, runtime-permission

Делаю запрос пермишена `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, подтверждаю першишен и пробую получить содержимое дериктории

```
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + "/Camera").listFiles()
```

Все получается, но если делаю вот такую последовательность

> Запрос пермишена -> отказ -> еще раз запрос пермишена -> подтверждение -> получение содержимого дериктории

то получаю `null`. Но если закрываю приложение и открываю его снова(пермишен остался подтвержденным), то все работает.

Такое впечатление, что после отказа и последующего подтверждения система все равно возвращает `null` в этой сессии. И только после закрытия и открытия начитает работать правильно

Что делаю не так?

Кто сталкивался?

**EDIT**

Имплементация во фрагменте запроса пермишена

```
private fun checkPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            activity!!,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        model.requestContent()
    } else {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            Constants.REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when (requestCode) {
        Constants.REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE -> {
            grantResults.forEach {
                if (it != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    model.permissionDenied()
                    return
                }
            }

            model.requestContent()
        }

        else -> super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы как то кастомизировали диалог запроса пермишенов?

Comment: @V.March добавил в вопрос код.